# About the usage of "if" in Erlang language

Tags: if-statement, erlang

This is my code:

```
    lists:foreach(fun(Method, Value)->
                      ServerName = method_to_servername(Method),
                      if
                          Value ==0 andalso whereis(ServerName) =/= undefined ->
                              supervisor:terminate_child(flowrate, whereis(ServerName));
                          Value =/= 0 andalso whereis(ServerName) == undefined ->
                              supervisor:start_child(?MODULE, [Method]);
                          Value =/=0 andalso whereis(ServerName) =/= undefined ->
                              gen_server:call(method_to_servername(Method),
                                              {update_config,
                                               {DesAddress, Method, RateLimitList,
                                                QueueTime,
                                                MinRetry, MaxRetry, Callback}} );
                          true -> ok
                      end
              end, ?ALL_METHODS).
```

when i compile the code, i meet this problem :`illegal guard expression`, can you give me some advise.

Answer (score 3):

The tests in an `if` expression are called guard sequences.  Only a limited number of functions are allowed in guard sequences, and `whereis` is not one of them.  See [the section on Guard Sequences in the Erlang Reference Manual](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id80042) for the complete list.

As a consequence, most Erlang programmers rarely use `if`.  Using `case` often gives more natural and concise code.  Your example could be written as:

```
lists:foreach(fun(Method, Value)->
                  ServerName = method_to_servername(Method),
                  case {Value, whereis(ServerName)} of
                      {0, ServerPid} when is_pid(ServerPid) ->
                          supervisor:terminate_child(flowrate, ServerPid);
                      {_, undefined} when Value =/= 0 ->
                          supervisor:start_child(?MODULE, [Method]);
                      {_, ServerPid} when is_pid(ServerPid) ->
                          gen_server:call(method_to_servername(Method),
                                          {update_config,
                                           {DesAddress, Method, RateLimitList,
                                            QueueTime,
                                            MinRetry, MaxRetry, Callback}} );
                      _ -> ok
                  end
          end, ?ALL_METHODS).
```

Comment: I suggest to use "when is_pid(ServerPid)" in guards

Answer (score 0):

With this code you have several issues:

1. `lists:foreach/2` requires fun with arity one as first argument, you
   have with two.  I guess you have ?ALL_METHODS macros defined similar
   to this: `-define(ALL_METHODS, [{method1, 1}, {method2, 2}, ...])` then you could fix it with wrapping fun's arguments in tuple: `fun(Method, Value)` will be `fun({Method, Value})`
2. With `whereis(ServerName) =/= undefined` you have possible race condition, when `whereis(ServerName)` return `pid()` at first, then process for some reason dies and on the next step it will be `undefined` (but it is hard to say 100% sure without context).
3. You do `method_to_servername(Method)` twice.

And about your question, guard functions in Erlang do allow only certain [subset](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id80042) of functions.