# Why Are So Many Guard Expressions in Ifs Illegal?

Tags: erlang

I am writing a function that will push a value to a list on a map if the key already exists, or init the key on the map with a new list if it does not already exist.

I tried making this part of the function guard expression but adding this guard expression to the function was illegal. I then tried making this an if but once again the guard expression was illegal. Finally I used a case which was fine.

I think the case is preferred here. But I'd like to understand *why* this guard expression is *illegal*. What does erlang see that makes it illegal?

If:

```
map_push(M, R, V) ->
  if
    maps:is_key(R, M) == true -> #{R := Row} = M, M#{R := [V|Row]};
    maps:is_key(R, M) == false -> #{R => [V]}
  end.

---

illegal guard expression
%   42|     maps:is_key(R, M) == false -> #{R => [V]}
%     |     ^
```

Case:

```
map_push(M, R, V) ->
  case maps:is_key(R, M) of
    true -> #{R := Row} = M, M#{R := [V|Row]};
    false -> #{R => [V]}
  end.
```

Comment: See also this question: [Why does Erlang if statement support only specific functions in its guard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48783536/113848)

Answer (score 3):

Well, actually it is not ***that*** complex if we carefully read the docs :)

```
Valid guard expressions are the following:

    - Variables
    - ...
```

So instead of calling the function `maps:is_key` inside the if clause, you need to save the value of the function into a variable so that the `evaluation of a guard expression can be guaranteed to be free of side effects`:

```
map_push(M, R, V) -> 
    IsKey = maps:is_key(R, M), 
    if
        IsKey == true -> #{R := Row} = M, M#{R := [V|Row]};
        IsKey == false -> #{R => [V]}
    end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Not just any `function` is allowed inside [`Guard Expressions`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#guard-expressions).

For this particular one, however you can give this a try...

```
map_push(M, R, V) ->
    if
        is_map_key(R, M) == true -> #{R := Row} = M, M#{R := [V|Row]};
        is_map_key(R, M) == false -> #{R => [V]}
    end.
```

---

### ***`WYSIWYG`*** => ***`WHAT YOU SHOW IS WHAT YOU GET`***

Comment: Ok so I understood that function guards could only use a handful of specific BIFs so you're also saying that applies to **all** guard expressions as well- even ifs. And by **WYSIWYG** you are commenting on how expression guards must not have side effects?

Comment: ***WYSIWYG*** doesn't have anything to do with `Guard Expressions` .. :-) It's for OP(s) on stackoverflow. A lot many times it happens that one tries to attend the question based on the provided text, then at times clarifications start pouring in  and then the original OP changes to something else or is meant to ask entirely a different thing. However, in your case that is not so... I put this line at the bottom of all my replies... just that's it!!!

Comment: Also, just for the sake of clarity, the above isn't a `function guard`, which are used to select a particular `function clause`, given a function has multiple clauses. In your case, the function is just one and not across many `clauses`, so calling it a `function guard` will be out of context... I think...